# Cross compile gdb for mips and make executable file small like one in OpenWrt

Tags: embedded, cross-compilation, mips

I would like to cross compile `gdb` for `mips`, but the normal version is too big for my small embedded device.

I was wondering how those guys on **OpenWrt** make it ***~3mb***.

I downloaded `gdb` `ipk`, extracted it and ran the binary but it's compiled for `mips32r2` and I need it for **MIPSI**

I can't find `src` files for their `gdb`, just the `make` file in few patches.

How can I compile `gdb` small enough using just `mips-gcc`?